# Is there a better way to call $(this) in a function using => in Coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I noticed that if I try to compile lines of Coffeescript like this:

```
$note.find('a.close').bind 'click', (event) =>
  $(this).parent().remove()
```

The `$(this)` compiles to `$(_this)`, which makes sense considering I'm using `=>`. The thing is, I don't want to have to use `->` in case I need to use local variables in this scope later.

Must I escape the second line with backticks to make `$this` compile correctly, à la:

```
`$(this).parent().remove()`
```

…or is there a better way?

**Update (12 Jul 2012):**

I ended up doing this:

```
close = -> $note.remove()
$note.find('a.close').bind 'click', (event) ->
  close()
setTimeout close, duration
```

I know it avoids the use of `this` altogether, but that seems like a cleaner solution than using the same `self = this` trick that developing in plain JS often requires.

Comment: @arnaud576875, it's a related problem, but the answers on the question you linked would not answer this question.

Comment: What is the problem that a simple `$this = $(@)` and `->` won't solve?

Comment: @muistooshort "The thing is, I don't want to have to use `->` in case I need to use local variables in this scope later."

Comment: How does `->` prevent you from using local variables in the closure?

Comment: "don't want to have to use -> in case I need to use local variables in this scope later" It's not clear to me what you mean by this. You have two scopes here: the inner, which is the function scope of "=>" and the outer, which is the scope where "=>" is declared. Irregardless of whether you use => or ->, variables declared in the inner scope will not be visible in the outer scope. You can however declare variables in the outer scope, and reference them in the inner scope. Either way, I don't understand how you expect to attach an event listener without using a function via -> or =>

Comment: `->` vs `=>` has nothing to do with "local variables", it just meddles with the value of `@`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/yqZCy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the element you clicked on, you can do:

```
close_button = $(event.currentTarget) // equivalent to $(this) here
close_button.parent().remove()
```

----- or -----

```
that = @
$note.find('a.close').bind 'click', (event) ->
    $(this).parent().remove()
    that.anotherFunc()
```

But it's not really answering your question, but it's a good alternative.
I would use the first solution myself when possible.

Comment: `event.target` and `this` may not always be the same.

Comment: In this case, it will though, right?

Comment: As long as `a.close` doesn't have any children, then yes.

Comment: It can be different in case of event bubbling, but that won't be the case here.

Comment: Right, `this` and `event.target` happen to be the same in this case, but not in event bubbling scenarios. It's not a very satisfying solution, though it would work.

Comment: As long as you know how it works, I think it's fine.

Comment: Or... you could use `->` and save `@` as a local variable... Not sure it's better.

Comment: [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) is the proper property, not `.target`

Comment: *sigh* I was hoping there'd be a better option than 1) avoiding using `this` or 2) doing the ol' `self = this` trick from plain JS. Thanks for your answers anyway – they really helped!

Answer (score 1):

You really want to use `->`.  The *only* thing that'll change is the value of `this` (or `@`) inside that function.  If you want to be able to use both the `this` you currently have and the `this` you want, you'll want to keep the current `this` in closure under a different name

The code now:

```
$note.find('a.close').bind 'click', (event) ->
  $(this).parent().remove()
```

The code if you need the `this` from the outer scope:

```
that = this
$note.find('a.close').bind 'click', (event) ->
  that.doSomething()
  $(this).parent().remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand you need just cache you variable

```
that = @

context.action (e) ->
  foo(that)
```